# Correct way to make a menu

Tags: python, menu

What is the correct way to create a simple menu?
I've used the following simple and standard way so far:

```
menu()
    print("1. Do A")
    print("2. Do B")
    choice = input("Choice")
    if choice == 1:
        stuff
    elif choice == 2:
        other stuff
    else:
        print("wrong input")
```

I read that this is not a very good way to do it, and that it becomes less effective when using big menus. I can't remember where I read that.
It didn't have an if-elif-else structure but started by checking if the given option was available (something like 'if choice in options') but that's about all I can remember.
So is there a better/more advanced way to build menus or should I stick with if-elif-else menus?

Comment: Note that `input()` in Python2 works differently than `input()` in Python3. So that the answers will work in your environment, please specify which version of Python you are using.

Comment: You shouldn't completely change the question. If you have a new question, search for an answer first, then try to create a [mcve].

Comment: If you have a new question please ask it by clicking the "Ask a New question" buttion

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a dictionary.

```
actions = {
    '1': ("Run function1", function1),
    '2': ("Run function2", function2)
}

for i in sorted(actions):
    print('Enter {} to {}'.format(i, actions[i][0]))

entry = input('Command: ')
if entry in actions:
    actions[entry][1]()
else:
    print("No such command")
```

In the dictionary `actions`, we store a tuple, where the first element is a description and the second element is some function.

Answer (score 1):

A more extensible way is to use a lookup map, which in Python is called `dict`:

If you have two functions, `stuff` and `other_stuff`, you can put them in a `dict`:

```
def stuff():
    print('Stuffing a turkey')

def other_stuff():
    print('Stuffing a cuddly toy')

menu = {1: stuff,
        2: other_stuff}
```

They can be accessed then using the keys `1` or `2`:

```
menu[key]()
```

e.g:

```
>>> menu[1]()
Stuffing a turkey
```

Comment: Note `input` will return a string `'1'` not an integer `1`.

Comment: This is not working for me. It runs the fucntions inside the library when I start the script, without me calling the library

Comment: I'm using python 3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: @RnRoger You're probably calling the function rather than putting the function's name into the dictionary, e.g. `{1: stuff()}` should be  `{1: stuff}`

Comment: Yea, I just figured it out. I've never called functions from dictionaries before so I didn't know that adding the () could be done somewhere else. I replaced the post above with my own code and added a question, could you take a look?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum. You shouldn't have changed the question to a new one. You ask a clear question and get a clear answer. Then move on.